# Check if column name exist in mysql table

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

i want to check if a particular column is present in my table or not. if it does not exist i want to add it using C programming language.

i tried following code:

```
mysql_query(sqlhnd, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
MYSQL_RES *confres = mysql_store_result(sqlhnd);
int totalrows = mysql_num_rows(confres);
int numfields = mysql_num_fields(confres);
MYSQL_FIELD *mfield;

while((row = mysql_fetch_row(confres)))
{
    for(i = 0; i < numfields; i++)
    {
        char *val = row[i];
        // do something with val...
    }
}
```

i want to compare val with the column name for example:

```
if( !strcmp(val,"column")) { create the column using alter table }
```

i am unable to do this part of the code

Comment: Can you show any examples of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways in MySQL, but I omit the C code here:

1. Do a `desc my_table` and look for your column in the output.
2. Simply `select your_col from my_table limit 1` and look for a *real* error (not an empty set)
3. Do `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db' AND TABLE_NAME='my_table';`

I'd prefer the 3rd option. It gives you a list of all column names of your particular table. I think with your attempt you don't get the column names but only their content.

Comment: sir i want to know if i do strncmp(row,"column_name"); will it work?

Comment: @rachitsrivastava Why don't you try? With my 3rd suggestion, I'd say _Yes_.